# File Input on FirefoxOS (Boot2Gecko!==Gecko?)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, gecko, google-chrome-os, firefox-os

I was developing a webapp for firefoxos (Boot2Gecko) and noticed, that there is no file-picker when clicking on an input(type=file). I came [across this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=801635) and it seems as if there hasn't been any movement for some time - luckily, we can at least now detect if its disabled.

But, wasn't boo2gecko/firefoxos supposed to run on the newest Gecko Engine and therefor support everything firefox does on android? I am very surprised about this fact. Is the situation similar with Chromium und ChromeOS that they don't support common web-features of eachother? I am still in shock about this inconsistency! Any insight about this divergence?

Comment: To answer "wasn't boo2gecko/firefoxos supposed to run on the newest Gecko Engine and therefor support everything firefox does on android": I don't remember them ever saying anything like that. FirefoxOS is a full operating system, but using html/js/css technologies for applications, with JS APIs for device interaction.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Well yes, FirefoxOS is an OS and Firefox is a Browser. Both run on the same engine though; Gecko. And firefoxOS has firefox (the browser) installed as well, so its hard for me to acknowledge the missing of this feature. Guess its feature-detect all the way!

Comment: it's *always* feature detect on the web. Modernizr all the way ;)

Answer (score 5):

Clicking an [input type="file"] element in Firefox OS should launch a "pick" web activity which gives the user the opportunity to pick a file from any app which uses this activity.

This was implemented in [bug 832923](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=832923)

Comment: it is actually not implemented yet in 1.1 (thats why I asked this question). But it seems as if it will land in the next release. Thanks for finding&sharing the bug!

Comment: As a workaround you could just issue the "pick" web activity directly on a platform that supports web activities. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Web_Activities